# how to stop react-piano-roll component from duplicating itself on state update

Tags: reactjs, canvas

i have a react component in which im using react-piano-roll component, the problem is when i update my component's state, react-piano-roll component replicates itself,

here is link code https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-water-q3eg4p?file=/src/App.js

thank you for your time and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling with this same issue and I had a look into the PianoRoll react component itself. The culprit section seems to be:

```
useEffect(function () {
  container.current.appendChild(pianoRoll.view);
});
```

After changing the section to read:

```
useEffect(function () {
  container.current.replaceChildren(pianoRoll.view);
});
```

the component seems to function as intended. From my understanding, `useEffect` runs on every render which is triggered by `setState`. As the append code is running each time `useEffect` is being triggered, the element is being duplicated each time.

My only fix I can see at the moment, unless the base react component is updated, is to make a copy of the component manually and call that instead.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mopsa-cppq2v?file=/src/App.js